# Servlet Mapping Issue

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc

I have a spring-based web application. In a controller I specified the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo/index.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView handleIndex(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    return new ModelAndView("public/foo/index");
}
```

The application web.xml servlet mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jib</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I make a request to the http://myhost/foo/index.hml everything works fine, but when I am trying to invoke http://myhost/foo/ - I receive a 404 error.

My question is how I can handle http://myhost/foo/ request exactly how I handle the http://myhost/foo/index.html request?

Comment: I don't do Spring MVC, so I may be utterly wrong and hence I don't post this as an answer, but have you tried to just specify it as a `<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>` in `web.xml` and supply a physical (but empty) file right there to fool the container that the file actually exists? This works for at least JSF (a component based MVC framework I'm familiar with, which also works with URL mappings like this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution is shown below

1. Change the servlet-mapping section in the web.xml file

   ```
   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>jib</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   ```
2. Change the @RequestMapping value parameter:

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = {"/foo/", "/foo/index.html"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView handleIndex(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
   return new ModelAndView("public/foo/index");
   }
   ```

Now, the handleIndex method handles all requests for **/foo/** and **/foo/index.html** paths

Hope it will help somebody

Answer (score 1):

You are not mapping anything to /foo, only /foo/index.html. You could probably teach your tomcat/jboss/whatever to redirect requests to index.html for directories but it won't happen automatically.

As @BalusC points out, adding index.html to  might do it (although I'm pretty sure that is the default of tomcat already). It's worth a try.